# Does Subversion *Really* Require ActivePython?

Tags: svn, python-3.x, activepython

It is listed as a requirement, but I'd rather not install it since I already have Python 3.1.1 installed.

If I must, are there any issues with the two Python versions co-existing (on Windows)?

From the ReadMe: http://www.collab.net/nonav/downloads/subversion/readme/svn1.6_server_client_windows.html
CollabNet Subversion Server and Client Installer for Windows
Version 1.6.6-4
Release Date: October 22, 2009

1. Platform and configuration

   Product: CollabNet Subversion Server
   Certified platforms: Windows XP SP2, Win 2003(Standard Edition) R2
   Apache version: 2.2.13
   ViewVC: 1.0.9 (requires ActiveState Python 2.5)
   Repository format: fsfs (bdb support not included)

Comment: Where do you see this listed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer to this is "no", Subversion doesn't require Python. Which Subversion package are you installing? I suspect that if you're installing the Python language bindings file, then it probably lists Python as a requirement. Otherwise, I'm not aware of anything in Subversion that specifically requires Python.

**Update**: I see you've listed [ViewVC](http://viewvc.org) as a part of that install package, which is a separate project (and happens to be written in Python). That explains it.

Comment: Yeah, ViewVC has the python dependency, not SVN itself.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion doesn't require anything, but some GUIs might.

http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#windows

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install as many versions of Python as you like on a machine. Since 3.x isn't fully compatible with 2.6, they're meant to co-exist.

The Apache binaries shouldn't have the requirement, nor the plug-ins, nor something like TortiseSVN. The CollabNet distribution, I'm guessing, is what you're looking at.